# Is $\{a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb Q\}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Set $$K=\{a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb Q\}.$$
Is $K$ a field ? I think it is, and I tried to prove that every element are invertible by searching the inverse : Let $a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3$.
$$(a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3)(\alpha +\beta \sqrt 2+\gamma \sqrt 3)=1$$
$$\iff \begin{cases}a\alpha +b\beta +c\gamma =1\\a\beta +\alpha b=0\\a\gamma +\alpha c=0\\ b\gamma +c\beta =0\end{cases}$$
and then, we solve this system, and everything should works. Nevertheless, I was wondering if there were an easier method. Any idea ?

Comment: What about closure for multiplication (e.g., $\sqrt2\times\sqrt3$)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: $\sqrt 2\times \sqrt 3=\frac{1}{2}(5+(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)^2)\in K$. Is this your question ?

Comment: @tiko Well, that's a statement you don't see every day.

Comment: @tiko: Why $(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)^2\in K$ ? Can you write it as $a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3$ ?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592773/prove-that-q-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-a-field). We have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \{a+b\sqrt{2} +c\sqrt{3} +d\sqrt{6}\ |\ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: @Surb: Does it mean that $K$ is not a ring ? (because it sounds that it's not stable for multiplication at the end...)

Comment: @Gae.S.: What do you mean ?

Comment: @tiko I was genuinely surprised by the commitment. Then again, the identity is wrong because it should be $-5$ instead of $5$, and most importantly there's the remark made by Surb to consider.

Comment: $\sqrt 6=a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3\implies \sqrt 6 -b\sqrt 2=c\sqrt 3 \implies -2b\sqrt{12}=3c^2-6-4b^2\implies \sqrt{12}\in \mathbb Q$.  So nope... not closed under mulitplication.  Nope, not a ring.  (But it is invertible.)

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558549/sub-rings-of-the-real-field-mathbbr/3940806#3940806) I explain why adjoining an algebraic number to $\mathbb{Q}$ generates a field. In the same way you can conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is a field. Note that here elements are linear combinations of the form $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6,$ where $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{Q}.$

In your case $K$ is just the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space spanned by $\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\}$ and not yet closed under multiplication. Once you take the multiplicative closure of $K$ by adjoining $\sqrt{6},$ you recover the above field.

Answer (score 1):

Well.  Consider:

$\frac 1{m+a\sqrt p}=\frac {m-a\sqrt{p}}{(m+a\sqrt p)(m-a\sqrt p)} = (m-a\sqrt{p})\frac 1{m^2 - a^2p}$.

So $m+a\sqrt p$ is invertible if $m^2 - a^2p$ is.

So $a + b\sqrt 2 + c \sqrt 3$ is invertible if $(a+b\sqrt 2)^2 - 3c^2$ is.

$(a+b\sqrt 2)^2 - 3c^2 = (a^2 + 2b^2 -3c^2) + 2ab\sqrt 2$ and that is invertible if $(a^2 + 2b^2 - 3c^2)^2 -4a^2b^2$ is.

And as the last monster is real it is.

This assumes that none of these terms are zero though....  we should probably do something about that.

If $m,a \in \mathbb Q$ and $a\ne 0$ then

$(m+a\sqrt 2)^{-1} = (m-a\sqrt{w})\frac 1{m^2 - 2a^2}$ and $m^2 - 2a^2$ can't be $0$ as $2 = (\frac ma)^2$ is impossible.  So $\{a + b\sqrt 2\}$ is a field.

If $m \in \{a + b\sqrt 2\}$ and $a \in \mathbb Q; a \ne 0$ then

$(m + a\sqrt 3)^{-1} = (m-a\sqrt 3)\frac 1{m^2 - 3a^2}$.  $m^2 -3a^2$ supposedly can not be $0$ as that would mean $3=(\frac ma)^2$ and supposedly $\sqrt 3\not \in \{a+b\sqrt 2\}$.

We can verify that last assumption fairly easily.  $\sqrt 3= a+b\sqrt 2; a,b\in \mathbb Q$ would imply $\sqrt 3 - a = b\sqrt 2$ which implies $3+a^2 -2a\sqrt 3=2b^2$.  But $\sqrt 3$ is irrational so that's only possible if $a=0$ but then we have $3 = 2b^2$ so $b^2 = \frac 32$ but that is impossible.

======

I guess I should point out that have only shown that $\{a+b\sqrt 2 + c\sqrt 3\}$ is invertible.   I *haven't* shown that it is closed under multiplication.

I *can't* show it it is closed under multiplication as it isn't.

$\sqrt 2\sqrt 3 \not \in \{a + b\sqrt 2 + c \sqrt 3\}$ as

$\sqrt 2 \sqrt 3 = a+ b\sqrt 2 + c\sqrt 3 \implies$

$\sqrt 6 -b\sqrt 2 = c\sqrt 3 \implies$

$6 + 2b^2 - 2b\sqrt 6\sqrt 2 = 3c^2 \implies$

$-4b\sqrt 3 = 3c^2 - 6 -4b^2\implies$

either $b \ne 0$ and $\sqrt 3 \in \mathbb Q$  or $b=0$ and $c^2 =2; c\in \mathbb Q$

So $\{a+b\sqrt 2+c\sqrt 3\}$ is *not* closed under multiplication and it is *not* a field.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The fact that you have a system with 3 variable and 4 constraint rather lok that there are no solution. Anyways :

1. If $K$ is a field, then it has degree at most $3$. In fact it's exactly 3 here : why ?
2. Notice that $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ belong to $K$. Therefore, if it's a field, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)\subset K$.
3. I let you conclude.

Comment: I see, if it would be a field, then it would have degree at least 4. Tks.